# How to make an extension not relocatable?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

I have an extension: https://github.com/CraigTyle/Mathexp

My task is to make the extension not relocatable: it should be possible to install the extension in any schema, but it should be impossible to change that schema.

I was told that this is how to do it: Do not use operators and use the `@extschema@` prefix for locally defined types and objects. well don't declare relocatable extension.

What exactly do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to change `relocatable` to `false` in the extension's control file.

Other than that, the recommendation you got is partly reasonable and partly nonsense.

You should define your functions like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION .... AS
$$ /* function body */ $$
SET search_path = @extschema@;
```

Then the `search_path` is fixed to `pg_catalog`, `pg_temp` and your extension schema for the duration of the function call.
That means that all access to objects without an explicit schema will only search in these schemas.

Then you don't have to worry about explicitly qualifying everything in the function with `@extschema@`, and you can use operators without having to worry, because `search_path` applies to operators as well. (You can also schema-qualify operators: `OPERATOR(schema.+)`, but that's obviously painful and harms readability.)

Comment: They wrote to me that it’s a bit wrong, since you need to use NOT GLOBAL names, but only LOCAL (quote: but you expose it globally in the session, and this is not good) to avoid conflicts with names in the public scheme for possible objects ( quote: what if there are objects with conflicting names in the public schema?
And you hide them from the user. look at extension as a module that you provide to users)

Comment: They are confused. There are no "global" and "local" objects. If you set the `search_path` the way my answer recommends, `public` will *not* be on the `search_path`. Only objects from the extension and system objects will be available.

Comment: They write again: check, after the function completes, what remains of the search_path?

Comment: Well, do. You will find that the previous `search_path` is restored after the function execution has completed.