# How to replace the operators on the procedure?

Tags: postgresql

Here, the operators are described in my code, but the task - How to replace it with procedures? :

```
CREATE OPERATOR + (PROCEDURE=sum_complex, LEFTARG=complex, rightarg=complex);
CREATE operator / (PROCEDURE = complex_div, LEFTarg = complex, RIGHTarg = float);
CREATE OPERATOR - (PROCEDURE=sub_complex, LEFTARG=complex, rightarg=complex);
CREATE OPERATOR ** (PROCEDURE = sqr_complex, leftarg = complex);
```

Comment: Are you working with [Mark_Flint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182984)?

Comment: Yes, we have almost the same task, only both of us cannot find a solution (:

Comment: Don't. Just use operators. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191727/6464308) to the other question.